# Dynamic order Numbering based on the view in sharepoint library 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, content-query-web-part

We are trying to do in this library, is create a column that will provide the “order” number of the listed item, per view.

So in one view there may be five items that show and they need to be numbered 1 through 5.
Then in another view there may be 15 items that show and in this case they would need to display the numbering 1 through 15.

We have 12 views in total that would need the dynamic order numbering.

Please advise.

We are not able to use Visual Studio to work on this, only SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SPD. On a page add the list view, then create a column and insert the following code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($thisNode/../*[not($thisNode/@ID=preceding-sibling::*/@ID)])" />
```

It should render the row number, no matter if you change the view order or filter some information.

[image: Sample list]

Hope this helps

Comment: this works perfectly when the number of items fits in one page.

incase paging happens for the view the numbering again starts from 1 on subsequent pages ! Any idea how that can be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a list **MyTestList**. It has currently two views **TestView1** and **TestView2**. To add serial number in the front follow the following steps:

1. Open the site in SPD
2. Open the List
   [image]
3. Edit the view in Split mode
   [image]
   [image]
4. Select the List, Go to '**List View Tools**' in the Ribbon > '**Design**' > '**Customize XSLT**' > '**Customize Entire View**'
5. This will convert the view in detail xslt
6. Now click on the attachment column. Right Click > Insert > Column To The Left
   [image]
7. Save the Page
8. Come to the Browser, Go to the List and Go to the View
9. Edit the Page of the View
   [image]
10. Add a Content Editor WebPart in the Page.
    [image]
11. Change the Content Editor Webpart's Chorme Type to 'None'. So web part's tool should not be shown in the page.
    [image]
12. Click the Content Editor WebPart and go the HTML and paste the following lines showing in the Image to refer the Script.js and jquery-1.11.1.min.js. This will refer the Script, which will show the serial number
    [image]
13. Go to the 'Site Assets' and upload [jquery-1.11.1.min.js](http://jquery.com/download/) and Script.js which will contain the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count=0;
    $('.ms-listviewtable tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function( index ) {
                count++;
                $(this).text(count);
            });
});
```

Above steps needs to be repeated in all the views you have. Best of luck.